# Variable issue in if clause

Tags: bash, rhel-7

I am trying to create a bash script to check and generate report on  CIS Benchmark for RHEL7 v2.1.0. I am getting some issue while handling variable in 'if' condition.
Here is my script:-

```
[root@test ~]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date) > ./report
echo $(date) > ./passed
echo $(date) > ./failed

echo -e "\n1.1.1.1\t Ensure mounting of cramfs filesystems is disabled" >> ./report
PROB='1.1.1.1'
CMD='modprobe -n -v cramfs'
RPUT="`$CMD`"
OPUT="install /bin/true"
if [ "$RPUT" == "$OPUT" ]
then
        echo -e "\nPASSED" >> ./report
        echo -e "$PROB" >> ./passed
else
        echo -e "\nFAILED" >> ./report
        echo -e "$PROB" >> ./failed
fi
echo -e "Your Output:\n $RPUT \nRequired Output:\n $OPUT " >> ./report
[root@test ~]#
[root@test ~]# ./test.sh
[root@test ~]#
[root@test ~]# cat report
Mon Aug 12 11:56:19 IST 2019

1.1.1.1  Ensure mounting of cramfs filesystems is disabled

FAILED
Your Output:
 install /bin/true
Required Output:
 install /bin/true
[root@test ~]#
```

Both the output are same but still the check is failing.

Answer (score 2):

I put  `declare -p RPUT OPUT` before the `if` statement which printed out put:

```
declare -- RPUT="install /bin/true "
declare -- OPUT="install /bin/true"
```

Now that extra space was creating problem so I added a space in `OPUT` variable. It resolved the problem.

Comment: Asking follow-up questions/requests in answers is not the right thing to do. Posting a new question is, but note that asking for software recommendations is off-topic here on Super User. I edited your answer.